# expect script to support two expected characters

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, shell, expect

I want to run `sshd restart` on Linux and Solaris machines via `expect`. ( my expect runs in my ksh script )

I created an expect script. When expect sees a prompt "#" it runs `sshd restart`.

I also run the same script on Solaris with a prompt ">". How to create one expect line that supports both prompts?

on Linux

```
expect #                {send "/etc/init.d/sshd restart\r"}
```

on Solaris

```
expect >                {send "/etc/init.d/sshd restart\r"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a glob-pattern: `expect {[#>]}`

or a regexp: `expect -re {#|>}` -- the regexp pattern can get more elaborate. I recommend you anchor prompt matching to the end of the line. Often prompts end with a space, so you could:

```
expect -re {[#>] ?$}
```

Comment: what agreat solution thx you very much for your great help -:)

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in an if statement by checking the output of uname -s, or by checking the output of:

> cat /etc/release
>
> cat /etc/redhat-release
>
> cat /etc/lsb-release

And use something like:

```
if [[ $(uname -s) == "Linux" ]];then
   expect #  {send "/etc/init.d/sshd restart\r"}
else
   expect >  {send "/etc/init.d/sshd restart\r"}
fi
```

I have not used ksh for some years so sorry if syntax is wrong!

Comment: yes but how to implemented the expect solution with Regular expression ( not by if then ..) , for example with expect -re ..... or something like that   . .. . .

Comment: expect -re {[$#] } should match both.